# Error installing ember-cli using 'nodesource/wheezy:5.0.0' using dockerfile

Tags: ember.js

Hi I'm trying to install ember-cli based off 'nodesource/wheezy:5.0.0'

I'm getting the following error..would it be possible to fix this issue? or do I need to go back to older versions of node (0.12)?

```
Step 0 : FROM nodesource/wheezy:5.0.0
5.0.0: Pulling from nodesource/wheezy
1d53ee5b1800: Pull complete 
74872ba2a3b0: Pull complete 
292a0889fc25: Pull complete 
d8e43051f9c0: Pull complete 
34a3fa49705c: Pull complete 
992d01b899f4: Pull complete 
120d2b6ae4ba: Pull complete 
651395105b63: Pull complete 
bf87c0988c7e: Pull complete 
38e00921614b: Pull complete 
038db7a41985: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:ace6600dde6399fa02df5c03c2ecf6b3e7de4745142639d13f502a04c1e62fa4
Status: Downloaded newer image for nodesource/wheezy:5.0.0
 ---> 038db7a41985
Step 1 : RUN npm install -g bower ember-cli
 ---> Running in 6c97ac90d722
/usr/bin/bower -> /usr/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower
/usr/bin/ember -> /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember

> bufferutil@1.1.0 install /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES user "undefined" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/5.0.0"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:0:
../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of 'template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T>)'
../../nan/nan.h:256:25: error: 'template<class T> v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T>)' previously declared here
../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: 'node::smalloc' has not been declared
../../nan/nan.h:661:35: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'callback'
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(char*, size_t, int)':
../../nan/nan.h:665:50: error: 'callback' was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan.h:665:60: error: 'hint' was not declared in this scope
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(const char*, uint32_t)':
../../nan/nan.h:672:67: error: call of overloaded 'New(v8::Isolate*, const char*&, uint32_t&)' is ambiguous
../../nan/nan.h:672:67: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:10:0:
/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::String>, node::encoding) <near match>
/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:31:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'uint32_t {aka unsigned int}' to 'node::encoding'
/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note: v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object> node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate*, char*, size_t) <near match>
/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/.node-gyp/5.0.0/include/node/node_buffer.h:43:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const char*' to 'char*'
In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:0:
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanNewBufferHandle(uint32_t)':
../../nan/nan.h:676:61: error: could not convert 'node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), ((size_t)size))' from 'v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Object>' to 'v8::Local<v8::Object>'
../../nan/nan.h: In function 'v8::Local<v8::Object> NanBufferUse(char*, uint32_t)':
../../nan/nan.h:683:12: error: 'Use' is not a member of 'node::Buffer'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.1.10-boot2docker
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
/usr/lib
`-- bower@1.6.5 

npm ERR! Linux 4.1.10-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bufferutil@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bufferutil@1.1.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bufferutil package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bufferutil
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using:

```
npm install -g ember-cli --no-optional
```